# Typesetting issue from MAC to Windows

Tags: psfrag

[image]

Hey Guys my Professor send me a LATEX document from MAC with the code

```
\begin{figure}
\centering

\psfrag{k}[][]{$k$}

\psfrag{y}[][]{$Y^{\prime }$}

\psfrag{x}[][]{$X^{\prime }$}

\psfrag{n}[][]{}

\psfrag{r}[][]{$O$}

\psfrag{a}[][]{$x$}

\psfrag{c}[][]{$y$}

\psfrag{m}[][]{$M$}

\psfrag{h}[][]{$\;\dfrac{1}{k}$}

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{fig3.eps}

\caption{The flow near the leading edge of a thin aerofoil.}

\label{fig3_ms}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the image with the PDF he sent and the one I get when I run this are different.

Why is that?

The top image is how it should look, the bottom is mine.

[image]

Comment: We are going to need more than 'different' ...

Comment: unlikely to be related to operating system. Are you using latex dvips ps2pdf (correct) or pdflatex (wrong) ?

Comment: I've edited the post, How do I change ps2pdf?

Comment: what command are you using to process the document, it should be latex, not pdflatex if you use psfrag.